# Compatible derailleurs with Shimano RD TY22 with dropout claw hanger

Tags: derailleur-rear

I have an older bike I love with a Shimano RD TY22 WD rear derailleur with a dropout claw hanger that needs to be replaced. I cannot find one listed anywhere. Are there any derailleurs available to replace this one? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in the link above, any Shimano 7/8/9 derailleur should work. You have to check for  direct mount vs traditional (hanger) mount and for the length of your cage. But you did not provide this info so we cannot help with that. Maybe TY22 has only one mount type and only 9ne cage length, but I do not know.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I’m a novice at this. How do I tell the difference between direct and traditional mount? Also, I’m not sure what the cage is, but I believe it’s the longer one.

Comment: So it is a direct mount with a longer cage like the one used on mountain bikes. From an answer to a similar question, it sounds like the Shimano MTB 7 should work. What do you think?

Comment: Direct Mount is the Shimano trade mark of a rather new (2012?) design/standard for derailleur hangers.  I don't believe the derailleur model you refer would have this standard, so searching for Direct Mount derailleurs might send you in the wrong direction.  Would it be possible to post a photo of the derailleur or your current derailleur hanger (the part of the bike where the derailleur is mounted)?  Searching for the model number gives a number of possible matches.

Comment: Or if you are not able to upload a photo, does your bike and derailleur look like photo 1: https://imgur.com/rYk1SgB or like photo 2: https://imgur.com/CAbNsSE note the different on how the derailleur is mounted: in photo 1 it's mounted in the wheel dropout and in photo 2 it's mounted separately below the wheel dropout.

Comment: It looks like photo #1.

Comment: Here’s a photo. Thanks for your help! https://imgur.com/gallery/fRP7jzO

Comment: Anyone have any idea what derailleur would work here? The one in the photo is a Shimano 7SIS RD TY22 WD. https://imgur.com/gallery/fRP7jzO

Comment: @Lou I have no experience with such a derailleur mount but you should be able to mount any current Shimano 7 speed with an adapter like this: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003UW4AXS or alternative you will need to find an "old-new-stock" of a derailleur with the same mount you have.  If you search for RD-TY22 on eBay you will find some with the same mount for around USD10 ex shipping.

Comment: I can also find other models that seems compatible with your frame: https://www.amazon.com/INKESKY-Shimano-Derailleur-RD-TZ31-Mountain/dp/B07GV14SLS/ref=pd_sbs_200_2/140-0505290-0790157 and https://www.modernbike.com/shimano-tourney-ty300-6-7-speed-rear-derailleur-with-frame-hanger as Vladimir wrote, check for the cage length if you can.

Comment: Thanks, Superman!!!!

Comment: @Lou You're welcome.  Just a few observations from the photo: the derailleur itself looks like in good shape.  However it does look incorrectly installed.  So maybe it's wiser to try to install it correctly first and see if it's actually necessary to replace it..

Comment: Thanks again! Yes, I’ll follow your advice. Happy riding!

Comment: Geesh, I was attempting to reinstall the derailleur only to discover the frame is bent. Darn. Goodbye bike. Any recommendations on a decent hybrid?

Comment: @Lou the frame looks like a steel frame.  If that's the case there is a good chance it can be bend back in shape.